# SAS: Merging two tables with identical columns while dropping null values

Tags: database, merge, sas, proc-sql

I'm not sure if the title does this question justice, but here it goes:

I have three datasets Forecasts1, Forecasts2 and Forecasts3. They are all time series data composed of a date variable and variables r1 through r241.

For a given r variable (lets just use r1-r3, and only Forecasts 1 and 2 for now) each dataset has only one row where the value isn't null, and it is a different row in each dataset.

Forecast 1 looks like this:

[image: Forecast1]

Forecast 2 looks like this:

[image: Forecast2]

I need to be able to combine them such that r1-r3 contain all the non-null values, without creating duplicate date rows to hold the null values.

So ideally the finished produce would look like this:

[image: Ideal final product]

I've tried various types of merges and sets, but I keep getting duplicate date rows. How would I go about doing this properly for all 241 (or more) variables? (specifically in SAS or Proc SQL?)

LINKS TO GOOGLE DOCS CONTAINING DATA:

Forecasts1: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iUEwPltU6V6ijgnkALFiIdrwrolDFt8xaITZaFC4WN8/edit?usp=sharing

Forecasts2: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lQGKYJlz6AAR-DWtoWnl8SwzCNAmSpj7yxRqRgnybr8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you post sample data? Photographs don't count since I cannot paste them into an editor.

Comment: I added two google drive links containing the spreadsheets. Will that be sufficient?

Comment: See my reply for an example of how to post data.

Comment: ahhh gotcha. I'll make note of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try the UPDATE statement?

```
data forecast1 ;
  input date r1-r3 ;
cards;
1 1 . .
2 . 2 .
3 . . 3
4 . . . 
;
data forecast2 ;
  input date r1-r3 ;
cards;
2 2 . .
3 . 3 .
4 . . 4 
5 . . .
;

data want ;
  update forecast1 forecast2 ;
  by date ;
run;

proc print; run;
```

Results

```
date    r1    r2    r3
  1      1     .     .
  2      2     2     .
  3      .     3     3
  4      .     .     4
  5      .     .     .
```

Answer (score 1):

I tend to approach these types of problems using `proc sql`.  Assuming one row per `date` in the data sets, you can use `full outer join`:

```
proc sql;
    select coalesce(f1.date, f2.date) as date,
           coalesce(f1.r1, f2.r1) as r1,
           coalesce(f1.r2, f2.r2) as r2,
           coalesce(f1.r3, f2.r3) as r3
    from forecast1 f1 full outer join
         forecast2 f2
         on f1.date = f2.date
```

Comment: How does this scale when you have 241+ variables though?

Comment: @JoshKraushaar . . . I would generate the code in a spreadsheet.  However, SAS offers other alternatives for iterating through columns in the data step.  However, this points out a folly of putting such data all in one row.  I would prefer to have one row per data item, rather than multiple columns.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a union query with aggregation. The only drawback is writing out the aggregates for all 241 columns in outer query.

```sql
proc sql;
   SELECT sub.date, Max(sub.r1) AS R1, Max(sub.r2) AS R2, Max(sub.r3) AS R3, ...
   FROM
     (SELECT *
      FROM Forecasts1 f1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT *
      FROM Forecasts2 f2) As sub
    GROUP BY sub.date
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

A different solution would be to append all and delete rows where all are missing.

```
data want; 
  set forecast1-forecast3 indsname=fc;
  model = fc; *store name of forecast model;
  if nmiss(of r1-r3) = 3 then delete;
run;
```

Comment: oh thats extremely efficient, I think thats probably the ideal solution for this. Thank you!